# How to permanently remove a charm from the juju charms store?

Tags: juju

I have already added a charm in juju charms store. Now I want to remove from the charms store.  Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? The charm store is a community maintained store, indivuduals really can't remove charms from the store.

Answer (score 3):

There is a subtle difference between the official Juju Charm Store and charms in the personal name space.

Once a charm has been accepted into the [Juju Charm Store](http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms) by the review process it is maintained by the community and can not be removed from the store.

If however you have a charm in your personal name space (lp:~username/charms/ubuntu-series/charm-name/trunk) you can delete it from Launchpad.

Go to:  https://code.launchpad.net/~username/charms/ubuntu-series/charm-name/trunk

If you own the branch and are logged in, you can delete the branch by clicking on "Delete branch" button.  The next screen will warn you that **Branch deletion is permanent.** and ask you to confirm.

Comment: The Juju Charm Store is no longer tied directly to Launchpad. Is it still possible to delete a charm in one's personal namespace? How?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is really answered in [Jorge Castro's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504046/how-to-remove-the-charm-from-juju-charms-store-permanently#comment680428_504046):

> The charm store is a community maintained store, indivuduals really can't remove charms from the store.

Answer (score 2):

The Charm Store has changed since my original answer over 2 years ago.

Users can not remove charms, but they can revoke permissions on the charm so no one other than the author can see them. To remove permissions from the charm use `charm revoke cs:~username/charm-name --acl read everyone`

Hope that helps.